# Making D3 like Force-Directed Graph with PNGs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to make D3 like Force-Directed Graph (example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) with PNGs (meaning the dots should be pictures).

Here is a visual idea: [image]

A different approach I tried is to map each graphic element into parallax.js (http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) and draw a line between the center of each graphic element, but I do not know how to do that, just yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you didn't post **your** code to create the force, I'll provide a general answer. You may have to adapt it according to your specific code.

The basic idea here is appending group elements for each node, and appending both the circles and the images to those groups. Here I'm using 40x40 PNGs:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("foo")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .call(d3.drag()
         .on("start", dragstarted)
         .on("drag", dragged)
         .on("end", dragended));

 var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", 20)
     .attr("stroke", "gray")
     .attr("fill", "none");

 var nodeImage = node.append("image")
     .attr("xlink:href", d => d.image)
     .attr("height", "40")
     .attr("width", "40")
     .attr("x", -20)
     .attr("y", -20);
```

The url of each image is in the data array of the nodes:

```
 var nodes = [{
     "id": "foo",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/chrome/48/Google-Chrome-icon.png"
 }, {
     "id": "bar",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/carlosjj/mozilla/48/Firefox-icon.png"
 }, {
     "id": "baz",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/johanchalibert/mac-osx-yosemite/48/safari-icon.png"
 }, {
     "id": "barbaz",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ampeross/smooth/48/Opera-icon.png"
 }];
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var width = 300;
 var height = 200;

 var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);

 var nodes = [{
     "id": "Chrome",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/chrome/48/Google-Chrome-icon.png"
 }, {
     "id": "Firefox",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/carlosjj/mozilla/48/Firefox-icon.png"
 }, {
     "id": "Safari",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/johanchalibert/mac-osx-yosemite/48/safari-icon.png"
 }, {
     "id": "Opera",
     "image": "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ampeross/smooth/48/Opera-icon.png"
 }];

 var edges = [{
     "source": 0,
     "target": 1
 }, {
     "source": 0,
     "target": 2
 }, {
     "source": 0,
     "target": 3
 }];

 var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
     .force("link", d3.forceLink())
     .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
     .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

 var links = svg.selectAll("foo")
     .data(edges)
     .enter()
     .append("line")
     .style("stroke", "#ccc")
     .style("stroke-width", 1);

 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

 var node = svg.selectAll("foo")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .call(d3.drag()
         .on("start", dragstarted)
         .on("drag", dragged)
         .on("end", dragended));

 var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", 20)
     .attr("stroke", "gray")
     .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
     .attr("fill", "white");

 var nodeImage = node.append("image")
     .attr("xlink:href", d => d.image)
     .attr("height", "40")
     .attr("width", "40")
     .attr("x", -20)
     .attr("y", -20)

 var texts = node.append("text")
     .style("fill", "black")
     .attr("dx", 20)
     .attr("dy", 8)
     .text(function(d) {
         return d.id;
     });

 simulation.nodes(nodes);
 simulation.force("link")
     .links(edges);

simulation.on("tick", function() { 
     links.attr("x1", function(d) {
             return d.source.x;
         })
         .attr("y1", function(d) {
             return d.source.y;
         })
         .attr("x2", function(d) {
             return d.target.x;
         })
         .attr("y2", function(d) {
             return d.target.y;
         })

     node.attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")


 });

 function dragstarted(d) {
     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
     d.fx = d.x;
     d.fy = d.y;
 }

 function dragged(d) {
     d.fx = d3.event.x;
     d.fy = d3.event.y;
 }

 function dragended(d) {
     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
     d.fx = null;
     d.fy = null;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if I remove edge from the `edges` list and leave node without any edge - it doesn't appear. What should I do to see nodes even if they doesn't have any edges?

Comment: Thx for this great answer! can you please explain what attribute here changes the distance between the node in a resting state? I thought it might be the force but it doesn't affect their distance from one another.

Comment: It is `forceManyBody`.