# Why image doesn't attach to the nodes in this d3 code?

Tags: image, d3.js, svg

I was trying to use image as node in a force layout, however I don't know how to specify the x, y position of the image:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3: Force layout</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* No style rules here yet */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Width and height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 300;

    //Original data
    var dataset = {
      nodes: [{
          name: "Adam"
        },
        {
          name: "Bob"
        },
        {
          name: "Carrie"
        },
        {
          name: "Donovan"
        },
        {
          name: "Edward"
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          source: 0,
          target: 1
        },
        {
          source: 0,
          target: 2
        },
        {
          source: 0,
          target: 3
        },
        {
          source: 0,
          target: 4
        },
        {
          source: 1,
          target: 2
        },
        {
          source: 2,
          target: 3
        },
        {
          source: 1,
          target: 4
        }
      ]
    };

    //Initialize a simple force layout, using the nodes and edges in dataset
    var force = d3.forceSimulation(dataset.nodes)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(dataset.edges))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(w / 2).y(h / 2));

    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);


    //Create edges as lines
    var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(dataset.edges)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .style("stroke", "#ccc")
      .style("stroke-width", 1);

    //Create nodes as circles
    var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr('width', 15)
      .attr('height', 15)
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico");



    //Every time the simulation "ticks", this will be called
    force.on("tick", function() {

      edges.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I find the coordinates of all nodes, and have image clipped by the nodes if the nodes are circular and images are square?

And if the data is in json format, each node with its own image, how can i push the image name to the original data? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending `<image>` elements, not circles (the fact that you're using `selectAll("circle")` makes no difference). Therefore, you should use `x` and `y` in the `tick` function. Besides that, you should move the image by half the width/height:

```
nodes.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x - 8; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y - 8; });
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 300;

//Original data
var dataset = {
  nodes: [{
      name: "Adam"
    },
    {
      name: "Bob"
    },
    {
      name: "Carrie"
    },
    {
      name: "Donovan"
    },
    {
      name: "Edward"
    }
  ],
  edges: [{
      source: 0,
      target: 1
    },
    {
      source: 0,
      target: 2
    },
    {
      source: 0,
      target: 3
    },
    {
      source: 0,
      target: 4
    },
    {
      source: 1,
      target: 2
    },
    {
      source: 2,
      target: 3
    },
    {
      source: 1,
      target: 4
    }
  ]
};

//Initialize a simple force layout, using the nodes and edges in dataset
var force = d3.forceSimulation(dataset.nodes)
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(dataset.edges))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(w / 2).y(h / 2));

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


//Create edges as lines
var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(dataset.edges)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", 1);

//Create nodes as circles
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr('width', 16)
  .attr('height', 16)
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico");



//Every time the simulation "ticks", this will be called
force.on("tick", function() {

  edges.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  nodes.attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x - 8;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y - 8;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Also, mind that your nodes right now are not *circular*, and there is no image clipped. If you want to append images **and** circles, as it seems to be the case, you can try different approaches, like this one: [Making D3 like Force-Directed Graph with PNGs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42545531/5768908)

Comment: is there any reason in the other example for the grouped circle/image element, one has to use translate transform while specifying the cx cy of the circles doesn't work? nodeCircle.attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.cx - 8;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.cy - 8;
    });

and to clip into circle, does one need to specify a clipPath? thanks

Comment: @santoku That's because in the example I'm using group (`<g>`) elements to append the circles and the images. And yes, you need to use clipPath, but in that example the icons are already circular! Just like your GitHub icon.

Comment: i get the idea now, just wondering what's the downside of not using group, appending everything to circle for an understanding of the g element

Comment: You don't need to use groups if you don't want... but then, in the tick function, you'll have to move both circles and images. Another solution is using a pattern.